# How do I combine these two line plots together using seaborn?

Tags: seaborn

I want to combine these two plots together into one.  What is the recommended approach to do this? Is there a way to do it using a single dataframe?

```
sns.relplot(x="epoch", y="loss", kind="line", color='orange', ci="sd", data=losses_df);
sns.relplot(x="epoch", y="loss", kind="line", color='red', ci="sd", data=val_losses_df);
```

My data for first is the following, with columns in this order ['epoch'], ['loss']

losses_df

```
0.0 0.156077
0.0 0.013558
0.0 0.007013
1.0 0.029891
1.0 0.008320
1.0 0.003487
2.0 0.017474
2.0 0.006232
2.0 0.002457
3.0 0.013332
3.0 0.004897
3.0 0.001900
4.0 0.010947
4.0 0.003905
4.0 0.001594
5.0 0.009127
5.0 0.003195
5.0 0.001341
6.0 0.007751
6.0 0.002681
6.0 0.001157
7.0 0.006605
7.0 0.002218
7.0 0.000972
8.0 0.005630
8.0 0.001867
8.0 0.000832
9.0 0.004839
9.0 0.001671
9.0 0.000748
```

val_losses_df

```
0.0 0.048945
0.0 0.006090
0.0 0.002332
1.0 0.024670
1.0 0.006243
1.0 0.002337
2.0 0.022344
2.0 0.006609
2.0 0.002626
3.0 0.022037
3.0 0.007156
3.0 0.003080
4.0 0.022025
4.0 0.008209
4.0 0.003835
5.0 0.022751
5.0 0.009226
5.0 0.004209
6.0 0.024093
6.0 0.009950
6.0 0.004783
7.0 0.025410
7.0 0.011130
7.0 0.005279
8.0 0.028299
8.0 0.012204
8.0 0.005969
9.0 0.028623
9.0 0.013037
9.0 0.006519
```

And my plots so far (except I want them combined in one plot with a legend)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the two dataframes to one:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# losses_df = pd.read_csv(...)
# val_losses_df = pd.read_csv(...)

losses_df['type'] = 'losses'
val_losses_df['type'] = 'val_losses'

combined_df = pd.concat([losses_df, val_losses_df])

sns.relplot(x="epoch", y="loss", kind="line", hue="type", palette=['orange', 'red'], ci="sd", data=combined_df)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1):

`relplot()` is a Figure level function that creates a new Figure at each call.
Use `lineplot()` instead.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(x="epoch", y="loss", color='orange', ci="sd", data=losses_df, ax=ax);
sns.lineplot(x="epoch", y="loss", color='red', ci="sd", data=val_losses_df, ax=ax);
```

Comment: You probably also want to add `sns.lineplot(....., label=...)` to automatically create a legend